# error: overloaded method value "predict" with alternatives / Double does not take parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to build a simple linear model to predict label values using LinearRegressionWithSGD.
I converted the Dataset to get features and label and again converted to Labeled points to do the regression

```
val train = dftrain.withColumn("label", dftrain("col2")).select("features", "label")
val test = dftest.withColumn("label", dftest("col2")).select("features", "label")

val realout  = train.rdd.map(row => LabeledPoint(row.getAs[Double]("label"),DenseVector.fromML(row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector]("features"))))
val realout1  = test.rdd.map(row => LabeledPoint(row.getAs[Double]("label"),DenseVector.fromML(row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector]("features"))))
```

Now i'm fitting the model

```
val numIterations = 100
val stepSize = 0.00000001
//fitting the model with converted Labeled points Train Data
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(realout, numIterations, stepSize)
```

> ```
>  17/08/09 12:16:15 WARN LinearRegressionWithSGD: The input data is not directly c
>     ached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also uncached.
>     17/08/09 12:16:17 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fomm
>     il.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
>     17/08/09 12:16:17 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fomm
>     il.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
>     17/08/09 12:16:17 WARN LinearRegressionWithSGD: The input data was not directly
>     cached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also uncached.
>     model: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionModel = org.apache.spar
>     k.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionModel: intercept = 0.0, numFeatures = 1
> ```

It gives me some warnings and also it gives `Intercept` as 0.0 which i don't feel its correct. But when i predict the model, it throws me error.

```
val prediction = model.predict(realout1)

<console>:98: error: overloaded method value predict with alternatives:
  (testData: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vec
tor])org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[Double] <and>
  (testData: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)Double <and>
  (testData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector])org.
apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regressio
n.LabeledPoint])
       val prediction = model.predict(realout1)
                              ^
```

Also if I do this from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression),

```
// Evaluate model on training examples and compute training error
val valuesAndPreds = realout.map { point => val prediction = model.predict(point.features) (point.label, prediction) }

<console>:90: error: Double does not take parameters
       val valuesAndPreds = realout.map { point => val prediction = model.predic
t(point.features) (point.label, prediction) }

                  ^
```

I believe the steps are correct. But i have no idea why it's showing *overloaded method value predict with alternative* or *Double does not take parameters*

Answer (score 0):

```
val prediction = model.predict(realout1.map(_.features));
```

this one works fine. But i don't know how much correct this one is. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.